# Remove querystring from url - HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a LoginContainer component in my app, which contains two views, a login-form and a signup-form. So, basically these two components are on the same page, however, depending on which button the user clicks, only one of them gets rendered.

The forms work so far. After signing up, the user is supposed to be "redirected" to the login-form so he can sign in. This generally works, however, for some reason the values entered in the form (e.g name, email, password, password confirmation, ...) are added to the querystring and the string then looks something like this: `localhost:3000"?password=xyz&name=zyx'/Login`.

I tried many things (read below) but I can't seem to come up with a way to avoid this.

This is what my router looks like:

```
<HashRouter basename="/">
    <div className="module">
    <PrivateRoute
        exact
        path={'/private'}
        component={privatecomponent}
      />
      <Route
        path="/Login"
        component={Login}
      />
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
```

This is my signup page:

```
 submitHandler = () => {

    var formdata = {
        "email" : this.state.email,
        "password" : this.state.password,
        "passwordConf" : this.state.password2,
        "firstName" : this.state.firstName,
    }
    axios.post('/adduser', formdata)
        .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({signup : true});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }

  render() {

const bodyBlock = 
    <div className="signup">

      <form>

        //here's a bunch of input fields which I left out

          <div>
            <Button
              onClick={this.submitHandler}
            >
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>

   return (
      <div className="signup">
            {this.state.signup ? //
                <Redirect to="http://localhost:3000/#/Login" />
                : bodyBlock
            }
      </div>
    )
   }
```

I know this is a lot of code. I wasn't sure which parts you guys would need. If you find a part irrelevant, please let me know and I'll shorten the question.

Anyway, what I tried, instead of `<Redirect />` was:

1. simply using `Login` instead of the link I'm using in the code above
2. using `this.props.history.push("/Login")`
3. `window.history.replaceState("http://localhost:3000/#/Login")`
4. `<Link to="http://localhost:3000/#/Login" />`
5. `window.location.reload()`

I'm not really sure what else I could do. Also, since I'm not sending the values as querystring in my `axios.post` function, I don't understand why they are added to the querystring in the first place.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent the values from being added to the querystring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `e.preventDefault()` in your form `submitHandler`. By default, a form submit will refresh the page and add the form values as query params.

```
submitHandler = e => {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formdata = {
        "email" : this.state.email,
        "password" : this.state.password,
        "passwordConf" : this.state.password2,
        "firstName" : this.state.firstName,
    }
    axios.post('/adduser', formdata)
        .then(function (response) {
                this.setState({signup : true});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was a really stupid mistake, but at least I know now!